# Python 3 Tkinter: Como pegar um value/string de um RadioButton dentro de uma função?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Eu gostaria de pegar valor do sexo selecionado e imprimir na janela DadosSalvos, mas não funciona, nem mesmo os outros dados digitados como nome ou idade.
Eu possuo aqui uma janela principal onde irá exibir dois botões: CADASTRAR e SAIR. O botão sair ainda não possui o comando, mas o cadastrar sim, que é abrir a janela SALVADADOS (localizada no primeiro def/função do código. Nessa janela que irá abrir, há um botão CADASTRAR para que seja exibida uma outra janela, a DADOSSALVOS como já citada antes. É nessa janela que preciso que os meus dados digitados nos campos (Entry) e o sexo selecionado no RadioButton sejam salvos com o get() e exibidos como texto (Label) nessa janela DADOSSALVOS.

```
from tkinter import *

def entrar():
  #Janela Principal
  janela = Tk()
  janela.title("Salvadados")
  janela.geometry('400x600')
  #Textos e entrada
  Lab1 = Label(janela, text='Nome completo:')
  Lab1.pack()
  textao = Entry(janela, textvariable = var,borderwidth= 5,relief ='ridge')
  textao.pack()
  Lab2 = Label(janela, text = 'Idade:')
  Lab2.pack()
  textao2 = Entry(janela, textvariable = d,borderwidth= 5,relief ='ridge')
  textao2.pack()
  Lab3 = Label(janela, text = "Sexo:")
  Lab3.pack()
  RBTN1 = Radiobutton(janela, text = 'Feminino',variable = kw,value = 'Feminino').pack()
  RBTN2 = Radiobutton(janela, text = 'Masculino', variable = kw, value = 'Maculino').pack()
  Lab4 = Label(janela, text = "Estado:")
  Lab4.pack()
  #Comando para o botão
  def janelanova():
     k = Tk()
     k.title("DadosSalvos")
     k.geometry('100x120')
     L2 = Label(k,text='Dados salvos:',bg='Red',fg='White')
     L2.pack()
     L = Label(k,text='')
     L.pack()
     L3 = Label(k,text='')
     L3.pack()
     L4 = Label(k,text='')
     L4.pack()
     b = var.get()
     t = d.get()
     g = kw.get()
     #para imprimir também(sem usar label)
     print(b)
     print(t)  
     print(g)
     L.config(text=b)
     L3.config(text= t)
     L4.config(text=g)
#JanPrincipal
janelaprincipal = Tk()
janelaprincipal.title('Menu Principal')
janelaprincipal.geometry('1010x200')
janelaprincipal['bg'] = '#C1FFC1'
mensagem1 = Label(janelaprincipal,text='Seja bem-vindo à Programação de Eventos do IFSP - Câmpus ----, cadastre-se para visualizar os eventos e suas programações completas.',font = ' -size 12',bg= 'green',fg='white')
mensagem1.place(x = 1,y= 14)
botaocadastro = Button(janelaprincipal,text= 'Cadastrar',font='-weight bold -size 16',fg='white', width = 20,activebackground='#B4EEB4',command=entrar)
botaocadastro['bg']='green'
botaocadastro.place(x = 355,y=60)
botaosair = Button(janelaprincipal,text = 'Sair',font='-weight bold -size 16',fg='white', width = 20,activebackground='#B4EEB4') 
botaosair['bg']='green'
botaosair.place(x = 355,y=120)
#Variáveis
var = StringVar()
d = StringVar()
var2 = StringVar()
kw = StringVar()
mainloop()
```

Comment: A pergunta não ficou muito clara @Mikalayla. E a endentação não está correta. Você poderia tentar ser mais clara e corrigir isso?

Comment: Pergunta corrigida juntamente com o código.

Answer (score 0):

Ola @Mikalayla, o problema é que você ao criar as novas telas utilizou `Tk()`.

Por conceito `Tk()` define a sua janela principal, para outras telas é interessante utilizar `Toplevel()`.

Não fiz grandes alterações no seu código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""""""
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def entrar():
    # Toplevel() porque já existe uma janela principal (janelaprincipal = Tk())
    janela = Toplevel()
    janela.title("Salvadados")
    janela.geometry('400x600')

    Lab1 = Label(janela, text='Nome completo:')
    Lab1.pack()
    textao = Entry(janela, textvariable=var, borderwidth=5, relief='ridge')
    textao.pack()

    Lab2 = Label(janela, text='Idade:')
    Lab2.pack()
    textao2 = Entry(janela, textvariable=d, borderwidth=5, relief='ridge')
    textao2.pack()

    Lab3 = Label(janela, text="Sexo:")
    Lab3.pack()

    # kw = StringVar()
    RBTN1 = Radiobutton(janela, text='Feminino', variable=kw, value='Feminino')
    RBTN1.pack()
    RBTN2 = Radiobutton(janela, text='Masculino', variable=kw, value='Masculino')
    RBTN2.pack()

    Lab4 = Label(janela, text="Estado:")
    Lab4.pack()

    # Botão que irá chamar a nova tela ou tkinter messagebox.
    btn_salvar = Button(janela, text='Salvar dados', command=lambda: janelanova(var, d, kw))
    btn_salvar.pack()

    btn_salvar = Button(janela, text='Salvar dados (messagebox)', command=lambda: janela_confirmacao(var, d, kw))
    btn_salvar.pack(pady=10)


def janelanova(var, d, kw):
    k = Toplevel()
    k.title("Salvadados")
    k.geometry('100x120')
    L2 = Label(k, text='Dados salvos:', bg='Red', fg='White')
    L2.pack()
    L = Label(k, text=var.get())
    L.pack()
    L3 = Label(k, text=d.get())
    L3.pack()
    L4 = Label(k, text=kw.get())
    L4.pack()


def janela_confirmacao(var, d, kw):
    msg = f'Dados que serão inseridos:\nNome: {var.get()}.\nIdade: {d.get()}\nSexo: {kw.get()}'
    resposta = messagebox.askokcancel(title='Confirmar?', message=msg)
    print(resposta)
    if resposta is True:
        print('Você clicou em OK')
    else:
        print('Você clicou em CANCELAR ou fechou a janela')


def sair():
    janelaprincipal.quit()


# JanPrincipal
janelaprincipal = Tk()
janelaprincipal.title('Menu Principal')
janelaprincipal.geometry('1010x200')
janelaprincipal['bg'] = '#C1FFC1'

mensagem1 = Label(janelaprincipal,
                  text='Seja bem-vindo à Programação de Eventos do IFSP -Câmpus Jacareí,'
                       'cadastre-se para visualizar os eventos e suas programações completas.',
                  font=' -size 12', bg='green', fg='white')
mensagem1.place(x=1, y=14)

botaocadastro = Button(janelaprincipal, text='Cadastrar', font='-weight bold -size 16',
                       bg='green', fg='white', width=20, activebackground='#B4EEB4', command=entrar)
botaocadastro.place(x=355, y=60)

botaosair = Button(janelaprincipal, text='Sair', font='-weight bold -size 16',
                   bg='green', fg='white', width=20, activebackground='#B4EEB4', command=sair)
botaosair.place(x=355, y=120)

# Variáveis
var = StringVar()
d = StringVar()
var2 = StringVar()
kw = StringVar()

mainloop()
```

Deixei a janela que você criou para exibir os dados e adicionei um caixa de mensagem (`messagebox`) que realiza a mesma função com a vantagem de poder verificar qual botão foi pressionado.

Observações:

- **Sempre que possível** tente utilizar nomes mais claros que deixem subentendido o que cada elemento realiza. Mesmo que o código fique um pouco mais verboso.
- Futuramente tente dar uma olhada na documentação do Python referente ao [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tkinter.html), pois lá tem alguns exemplos de como criar o código utilizando classes, dependendo do tamanho do seu aplicativo utilizar classes pode ternar o código mais legível e fácil de dar manutenção.

Exemplo com classes utilizando o **seu código como base**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Exemplo"""

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class TelaCadastro(tk.Toplevel):
    """Classe TelaCadastro 2 herda de tk.Toplevel()."""

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        """Construtor."""
        super().__init__(**kw)
        # Definindo a cor de fundo da janela (tk.Toplevel).
        self['background'] = '#E57373'
        # Título da janela.
        self.title(string='Tela de cadastro')
        # Denifindo um ícone diferente para nova janela.
        # icon_png = tk.PhotoImage(file='../icons/icon.png')
        # self.iconphoto(False, icon_png)

        # Tamanho da janela.
        width = round(self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2)
        height = round(self.winfo_screenheight() / 2)
        self.geometry(newGeometry=f'{width}x{height}')
        self.minsize(width=width, height=height)

        # Inserindo um frame sobre a janela para posicionar os widgets.
        # Não é obrigatório, contudo mantém organizado o layout.
        self.container = tk.Frame(master=self)
        self.container.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.criar_widgets()

    def criar_widgets(self):
        label_nome = tk.Label(master=self.container, text='Nome completo:', anchor=tk.W)
        label_nome.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10)
        self.entry_nome = tk.Entry(master=self.container)
        self.entry_nome.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10, pady=(0, 10))

        label_idade = tk.Label(master=self.container, text='Idade:', anchor=tk.W)
        label_idade.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10)
        self.entry_idade = tk.Entry(master=self.container)
        self.entry_idade.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10, pady=(0, 10))

        label_sexo = tk.Label(master=self.container, text='Sexo:', anchor=tk.W)
        label_sexo.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10)

        self.kw = tk.StringVar()
        RADIOBUTTON = [('Feminino', 'Feminino'), ('Masculino', 'Masculino')]
        for texto, valor in RADIOBUTTON:
            radio_button = tk.Radiobutton(master=self.container, text=texto, variable=self.kw, value=valor, anchor=tk.W)
            radio_button.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10)
        self.kw.set('Feminino')

        label_estado = tk.Label(master=self.container, text='Estado:', anchor=tk.W)
        label_estado.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))

        button_salvar = tk.Button(self.container, text='Salvar registro', command=self.salva_registro)
        button_salvar.pack(pady=10)

    def salva_registro(self):
        msg = f'Dados que serão inseridos:\nNome: {self.entry_nome.get()}.\n' \
            f'Idade: {self.entry_idade.get()}\nSexo: {self.kw.get()}'
        resposta = messagebox.askokcancel(title='Confimar dados?', message=msg)
        print(resposta)
        if resposta is True:
            print('Você clicou em OK')
            self.destroy()
        else:
            print('Você clicou em CANCELAR ou fechou a janela')


class MeuApp(tk.Frame):
    """Classe herda de tk.Frame()"""

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        """Construtor"""
        super().__init__(master=master)
        self.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.criar_widgets()

    def criar_widgets(self):
        mensagem1 = tk.Label(master=self,
                             text='Seja bem-vindo à Programação de Eventos do IFSP - Câmpus Jacareí.\n'
                                  'cadastre-se para visualizar os eventos e suas programações completas.')
        mensagem1.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        botaocadastro = tk.Button(master=self, text='Cadastrar', command=self.abrir_tela_cadastro)
        botaocadastro.pack(fill=tk.X)

        botaosair = tk.Button(master=self, text='Sair', command=self.sair)
        botaosair.pack(fill=tk.X, pady=10)

    @staticmethod
    def abrir_tela_cadastro():
        TelaCadastro()

    def sair(self):
        self.master.quit()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title(string='Título do aplicativo')
# icon_png = tk.PhotoImage(file='../icons/icon.png')
# root.iconphoto(False, icon_png)
width = round(number=root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2)
height = round(number=root.winfo_screenheight() / 2)
root.geometry(newGeometry=f'{width}x{height}')
root.minsize(width=width, height=height)
app = MeuApp(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Vale notar que não existe um código que esteja certo ou errado, são apenas formas/paradigmas diferentes para se resolver o mesmo problema.

Comment: O código deu erro, disse que TopLevel não foi definido

Comment: Fiz um teste com ambos os código, inclusive copiando e colando o código da resposta e a execução foi normal. Verifique se você não está com algum erro na edentação do código.